# Bind checkbox and textbox to viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have to bind checkbox value and textbox value with model.Here I am using model to retrive and to post data as well.
I have tried few options but it didnt work.

Below is my code:

```
@model IEnumerable<ALDS.Web.Areas.AR.Models.ReportViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Standings";
}


    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>LR Date</th>
                <th>LR Line No</th>
                <th>Issue</th>
                <th>Correction Response</th>
                <th>Remarks</th>
                <th>Submission</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.InsertDate
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.LRLineID <a href="">View</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>Margin % incorrect</td>
                    <td><label for="cbox1">Corrected</label>  <input type="checkbox" name="Corrected" value="@item.Status"  />     <label for="cbox1">Neglected</label>  <input type="checkbox" name="Neglected" value="@item.Status"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="@item.Comments"/></td>
                    <td><a href="@Url.Action("Update","Error",Model)">Submit</a></td>

                    </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I have to send the checkbox and textbox value to controller.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Render the inputs using the HtmlHelpers provided by MVC. They will make sure that the `id` and `name` attributes of the generated `<input/>` are in a format that can be processed by the MVC ModelBinder.

Also, to post back lists of objects, use a `for` loop, so that the items get an index understood by the ModelBinder.

Wrap the inputs in a `<form>` to be posted to the Controller. With the following example, the model will be posted to the "Update" action in "ErrorController" when the user clicks the "Submit" button. `myFormClass` and `myFormId` are not neccessary, I just wanted to show how you could add them if needed.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Update", "Error", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "myFormClass", id = myFormId })) {
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Length; i++) {
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].Status)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].Status)

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].Comments)
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m[i].Comments) // multi line 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Comments)  // single line 
    }

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

`LabelFor` will try to find `[Display(Name="some_resource_key", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]` attributes on the property in the ViewModel to look up the translated text to be used as label in the Resources.resx.

**EDIT** As Antoine mentioned, you have to provide inputs for ALL ViewModel properties that shall be posted back. You can render `<input type="hidden"/>` using `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Id)`.

Comment: Don't forget to tell the OP to put his model id's inside `.hidden()`

Comment: it didnt work. :|

Comment: You haven't put Form Tag "Using Form... " ?

Comment: Added the `<form>` tag to my answer.

Comment: You should note that the model needs to be `IList<T>` (not `IEnumerable<T>`) for a `for` loop.